# Wanting to use a static method in a non static method from different classes

Tags: java, android

I am very new to Java and making Android projects but I want to basically turn on "do not disturb" at a specific time. I have tried making sub class and making all the things static/non static. Nothing seems to be working. I need two extends which I cannot use in the same class. Is there a solution/better way to do this? If I'm not mistaken Receivers need to be static while the myactivity class cannot be.

Class MainActivity.java This is where the DND function is

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private Context mContext;
    private Activity mActivity;

    TimePicker timePicker;

    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    public LinearLayout mRootLayout;
    static Intent intent;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //getting the timepicker object
        timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

        //attaching clicklistener on button
        findViewById(R.id.buttonAlarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //We need a calendar object to get the specified time in millis
                //as the alarm manager method takes time in millis to setup the alarm
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                            timePicker.getHour(), timePicker.getMinute(), 0);
                } else {
                    calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                            timePicker.getCurrentHour(), timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
                }


                setAlarm(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            }
        });
    }

    private void setAlarm(long time) {
        //getting the alarm manager
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //creating a new intent specifying the broadcast receiver
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyAlarm.class);

        //creating a pending intent using the intent
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);

        //setting the repeating alarm that will be fired every day
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, time, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static void changeInterruptionFilter(int interruptionFilter) {


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) { // If api level minimum 23
            mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(interruptionFilter);
            // If notification policy access granted for this package
            if (mNotificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {

                mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(interruptionFilter);
                // Set the interruption filter

            } else {


                intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);

                //ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(()-> Context., Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY)


                startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Class MyAlarm.java this is where my receiver is.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MainActivity.changeInterruptionFilter(2);
        //you can check the log that it is fired
        //Here we are actually not doing anything
        //but you can do any task here that you want to be done at a specific time everyday
        Log.d("MyAlarm", "Alarm just fired");

        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        android:enabled="false">

        android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- registering the receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyAlarm"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```
````

Comment: static just means the same instance everywhere. so, you could in theory, just copy the content of this method into both places, right ? i'm not saying that's the best solution, just saying it's an attempt you haven't listed

Comment: Since I need to extend to two different classes, I cannot paste the content into the same class since I cannot extend to two calsses with the same standard class. if that makes sense.

Comment: Why do you need to extend two classes? Can't you copy and paste the contents of `changeInterruptionFilter` into your receiver class?